# Add image caption under image thumbnail in WooCommerce single product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails, hook-woocommerce, caption

I'm trying to add the image caption under each image thumbnail on WooCommerce single product page.

Here you can see where I want the text to be shown (presently "undefined")

[image]

I want to add the individual caption text (not the product title, the image caption. Each image has a different caption).

[image]

Is there an easy way to do that? I'm using ToolSet and can add JavaScript snippet if needed.

I saw a post that talks about this but can't figure out where to put that code :

[Show caption under product gallery in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592557/show-caption-under-product-gallery-in-woocommerce)

I also tried to add this code to my Toolset JavaScript editor but I'm getting the Product title, not the image title (or caption). [(Suggested as a solution in that post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618634/add-title-underneath-woocommerce-product-gallery-images)

```js
jQuery(window).load(function(){
if( jQuery('body').hasClass('single-product') ){
var imgtitles = [];
jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper').children('div').each(function(){
    var imgTitle = jQuery(this).find('a').find('img.wp-post-image').attr('title');
    console.log(imgTitle);
    imgtitles.push(imgTitle);
});
if( jQuery('ol.flex-control-nav').length && jQuery('ol.flex-control-nav').children().length>1 ){
    for(i=0; i<imgtitles.length; ++i){
        jQuery('ol.flex-control-nav li:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').append('<span class="flexthum-title">'+imgtitles[i]+'</span>');
    }
}
}});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
if( jQuery('body').hasClass('single-product') ){
var imgtitles = [];
jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper').children('div').each(function(){
    var imgTitle = jQuery(this).find('a').find('img').attr('data-caption');
    console.log(imgTitle);
    imgtitles.push(imgTitle);
});
if( jQuery('ol.flex-control-nav').length && jQuery('ol.flex-control-nav').children().length>1 ){
    for(i=0; i<imgtitles.length; ++i){
        jQuery('ol.flex-control-nav li:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').append('<span class="flexthum-title">'+imgtitles[i]+'</span>');
    }
}
}});
```