# Add image caption under the first image in a WooCommerce single product page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, caption

Using the *[Add image caption under image thumbnail in WooCommerce single product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54855268/add-image-caption-under-image-thumbnail-in-woocommerce-single-product-page/54860967#54860967)* answer's code, I would like to do the same thing, but just for the first image and not for all thumbnails.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please check my anwser.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below hooks,

```
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'thumb_add_caption', 10, 4 );
function thumb_add_caption( $html, $id, $parent, $class) {
   $attachment = get_post( $id );
   $img_cap = "<div class=\"img-cap\"><span class=\"cap-text\">{$attachment->post_excerpt}</span></div>$html";
   return $img_cap;
}
```

or

```
function add_caption_below_product_image() {

    echo '<h4 style="text-align: center;">';
    $caption = get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() )->post_excerpt;
    echo $caption;
    echo '</h4>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'add_caption_below_product_image' );
```

Comment: First code break my site Second doesn't work

I use Divi template the attribut of caption is data-caption

Answer (score 0):

I have something with this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper').each(function(){
    $('.woocommerce-product-gallery__image', this).after('<div class="legende_image"></div>');
    $('.legende_image', this).html($('img', this).attr('data-caption'));
});   });
```

and this css code

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper {
position: relative;}

.legende_image {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #000;
font-style: italic;
line-height: 1em;
font-size: 14px;
color: #fff;
bottom:0;
white-space: pre-line;}
```

But the caption stay on top of my image
Do you have an idea ?
Thx